# Asp MVC Entity Framework Check if User has Permission or Role

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, oop

I have the following application user model. I want to implement methods to check if a user has a role and if a user has permission. A user can be in multiple roles and a role can have multiple permissions.

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{

    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ApplicationRole> Roles { get; set; }

    public bool HasRole(string _role)
    {
        return Roles.Any(r => r.Name == _role);
    }


    public bool HasPermission(string _permission)
    {
        return Roles.Any(r => r.Permissions
                  .Any(p => p.Name == _permission));
    }
}
```

This is my permissions and roles class:

```
public class Permission
{
    public byte Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual List<ApplicationRole> Roles { get; set; }

}


public class ApplicationRole : IdentityRole
{
    public ApplicationRole() : base() { }
    public ApplicationRole(string name) : base(name) { }

    public virtual ICollection<Permission> Permissions { get; set; }

    public bool IsPermissionInRole(string _permission)
    {
        return Permissions.Any(p => p.Name == _permission);
    }

}
```

In Laravel I can do something as simple as this:

```
public function hasRole($role)
{
    if (is_string($role)) {
        return $this->roles->contains('name', $role);
    }
    return !! $role->intersect($this->roles)->count();
}

public function hasPermission(Permission $permission)
{
    return $this->hasRole($permission->roles);
}
```

How can I do something similar in ASP MVC? Note Im aware of the built in `User.IsInRole("Admin")` method but how would you implement the hasPermission method?

*** UPDATE *** on the following line of the ApplicationUser class I get intellisense message:

```
public virtual List<ApplicationRole> Roles { get; set; }

ApplicationUser.Roles hides inherited member `IdentityUser<string, IdentityUserLogin, IdentityUserRole, IdentityUserclaim>.Roles
To make the current memeber override that implementation add the overide keyword
```

Not sure what that means but does this navigation property allow me to get the roles assigned to the user or just a list of all roles in the table in which case the hasRole and has Permission methods won't work?

Comment: you need to extend authorize attribute for action & user specific roles

Comment: I put the answer for MVC 5 below. I am not impressed with the the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

What about something like:

```
public bool HasPermission(string _permission)
{
    return Roles.Any(r => r.IsPermissionInRole(_permission));
}
```

### Update:

Your *Identity models* are not correct. Correct models and corrected *HasPermission* method is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38712909/1380428).

Comment: I get error `IdentiyUserRole does not contain a definition for Permissions`

Comment: oo, I thougt that  *public virtual ICollection<IdentityUserRole> UserRoles* is *public virtual ICollection<ApplicationRole> UserRoles*

Comment: IdentityUserRole doesn't contain a defintion for Permissions. I think your getting confused with ApplicationRole. For that I would have to extend the IdentityUseRole class and add the Permission navigation?

Comment: No, in your ApplicationUser you have property UserRoles, type of which is *ICollection<IdentityUserRole>* can you change its type to *ICollection<ApplicationRole>*?

Comment: Shouldn't I rename `public virtual ICollection<IdentityUserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }` to `public virtual ICollection<ApplicationRole> Roles { get; set; }` otherwise arn't I just retrieving a list of Roles which are not necessarily assigned to the user or I'm I missunderstood how these navigation properties work?

Comment: Yes, I am telling the same thing :). I am editing my answer, because I have just noticed that you have method called *IsPermissionInRole*.

Comment: @Adli please see my update. Does using the navigation property `public virtual ICollection<ApplicationRole> Roles` give me a list of all roles in the table or only the roles assigned to the user?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118797/discussion-between-adil-mammadov-and-ozzii).

Comment: I am not impressed with this answer. The answer immediately below works for MVC 5. Downvote.

Answer (score 0):

I am very disappointed in the poor answers given above. I'm not saying those answers are wrong. But y'all are making things WAY too complicated. I'm using MVC 5 with C#. *All* you have to do is check the claims object for the user and see if they have a particular permission. This code checks the Edit permission to see if it is active or not.

```
   @if (@User.HasClaim("Edit", "True")) 
    {
    <show your button or whatever here...>

    }
```

To discover this fact, I did an F12 on @User.IsInRole, saw that there is a call for HasClaim that requires a type and value, and then put a breakpoint on the @if statement above and see that when a user has this permission, the @User has a Claims object that contains {Edit: True}. When it's false, there is no {Edit: False} object, so it fails the test.

ALSO: They have to logout and log back in for this value to be updated. So if you change a user's permissions while they are in a browser session, it will not take effect until they logout and log back in. Which is a good argument for automatically ending their session after 30 minutes of inactivity.