# ASP MVC Build Throwing Warning For ApplicationUser Roles Navigation Property?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-identity-2

I have the following ApplicationUser Model:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ApplicationRole> Roles { get; set; }

    public bool HasRole(string _role)
    {
        return Roles.Any(r => r.Name == _role);
    }

    public bool HasPermission(string _permission)
    {
        return Roles.Any(r => r.Permissions
              .Any(p => p.Name == _permission));
    }
}
```

But when I run a build I get the following warning message:

```
ApplicationUser.Roles hides inherited member 
'IdentityUser<string, IdentityUserLogin,IdentityUserRole, IdentityUserClaim>.Roles. 
To make the current member override that implementation, add the overide keyword. Otherwise 
add the new keyword.
```

Is something wrong with my implementation or should it be done differently? I have added the Roles navigation property so that I can implement the HasRole and HasPermission methods.

My Permission and  ApplicationRole models are implemented as follows:

```
public class Permission
{
    public byte Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual List<ApplicationRole> Roles { get; set; }
}


public class ApplicationRole : IdentityRole
{
    public ApplicationRole() : base() { }
    public ApplicationRole(string name) : base(name) { }

    public virtual ICollection<Permission> Permissions { get; set; }

    public bool IsPermissionInRole(string _permission)
    {
        return Permissions.Any(p => p.Name == _permission);
    }
}
```

Comment: I deleted my answer - after you explained why you needed to override `Roles`, I don't have anything useful to add - sorry about that! I don't know the IdentityRole / IdentityUserRole classes & their generic declarations well enough to give you an answer at the moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not have broad knowledge about *ASP.NET Identity*. But after a little search I can give you rough answer. *IdentityUser* should have proeprty *Roles* which inherits *IdentityUserRole* not *IdentityRole*. I think this model relates IdentityUsers and IdentityRoles. So, what you should do is create *ApplicationUserRole* class which inherits *IdentityUserRole*:

```
public class ApplicationUserRole : IdentityUserRole
{
    public ApplicationUserRole()
        : base()
    { }

    public virtual ApplicationRole Role { get; set; }
}
```

Inherit your ApplicationRole from `IdentityRole<string, ApplicationUserRole>`:

```
public class ApplicationRole 
    : IdentityRole<string, ApplicationUserRole>
{
}
```

Then use this class in your *ApplicationUser* class. To use ApplicationUserRole you need to inherit ApplicationUser  from `IdentityUser<string, IdentityUserLogin, ApplicationUserRole, IdentityUserClaim>` isntead of `IdentityUser`

```
public class ApplicationUser 
    : IdentityUser<string, IdentityUserLogin, ApplicationUserRole, IdentityUserClaim>
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    .............
}
```

Finally, change your *HasPermission* method of *ApplicationUser* to something like:

```
public bool HasPermission(string _permission)
{
    return Roles.Any(r => r.Role.IsPermissionInRole(_permission));
}
```

I am stating again, this is *rough* answer. For more information about extending Identity models, please refer to [this code project article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/798001/ASP-NET-Identity-Extending-Identity-Models-and-Usi).

Comment: I've done as per your suggestion but I still get warning: `ApplicationUser.Roles hides inherited member 
'IdentityUser<string, IdentityUserLogin,IdentityUserRole, IdentityUserClaim>.Roles. To make the current member override that implementation, add the overide keyword. Otherwise 
add the new keyword.` Maybe I need to rename `public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUserRole> Roles { get; set; }` to `public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }`?

Comment: @ozzii, I have updated my answer. Please check if it works

Comment: I followed your instructions and managed to get it working. The only additional thing was to remove the navigation property `public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUserRole> Roles { get; set; }` from ApplicationUser class. This is no longer needed because we are inheriting ApplicationUserRole via `public class ApplicationUser 
    : IdentityUser<string, IdentityUserLogin, ApplicationUserRole, IdentityUserClaim>`. If you update your answer I will mark it solution. Many thanks for your help.