# Asp.Net Identity 2.0 Return Roles (By NAME) with a LIST of Users

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-identity

I fear I must be missing something simple, but when I execute:

```
var results = UserManager.Users.Where(u => u.mgr == appUser.org || appUser.org == "corp");
```

I get a IQueryable collection of ApplicationUsers which match my requirements...
except... each ApplicationUser in the set has a property (collection) of Roles which only includes the UserId & RoleId and NOT the name of the role. I'm to believe that adding a .Include("???") to this linq query should allow me to bring the names of the roles back with each user... but I can not find the right expression to get there.

How may I retrieve the names of the roles each user in the set is assigned?

Comment: If you're looking to use `.Include()`, try one of the following. You could do `.Include(x => x.Roles)` as a lambda expression - *you will need `using System.Data.Entity`*. Alternatively you could do `.Include(nameof(ApplicationUser.Roles))` (if using C# 6.0 - where `ApplicationUser.Roles` is the class and property of the `Roles` to include). Both would `Include` the same property. By the looks of it, I guess you're using EF with `Users` as a `DbSet<T>` property on your context, right? Is your `Roles` property a navigation property?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In *ASP.NET Identity* *Roles* property of *ApplicationUser* is *ApplicationUserRole*. This table is *many-to-many* relationship between *ApplicationUsers* and *ApplicationRoles*. If you want to get other details of reles, you have to use `Include` as you stated yourself:

```
var results = UserManager
    .Users
    .Where(u => u.mgr == appUser.org || appUser.org == "corp")
    .Include(m => m.Roles.Select(r => r.Role));
```

As @GeoffJames notes, you have to add `using System.Data.Entity;` to your using list.

### Update

Generally your custom *Identity models* should be as below:

```
public class ApplicationUserRole : IdentityUserRole
{
    public ApplicationUserRole()
        : base()
    { }

    public virtual ApplicationRole Role { get; set; }
}
```

ApplicationRole should inherit I`dentityRole<string, ApplicationUserRole>`

```
public class ApplicationRole 
: IdentityRole<string, ApplicationUserRole>
{
}
```

ApplicationUser should inherit `IdentityUser<string, IdentityUserLogin, ApplicationUserRole, IdentityUserClaim>`

```
public class ApplicationUser 
    : IdentityUser<string, IdentityUserLogin, ApplicationUserRole, IdentityUserClaim>
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    .............
}
```

You can also see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38712909/1380428), it may help.

Comment: Note that you will need to use `System.Data.Entity` in order to create the `Include(m => m...)` lambda expression

Comment: in `(.Select(r=>r.Role))` "Role" does not resolve, but RoleId does. Which leaves me exactly where I started. The "Roles" relationship takes me ONLY to the AspNetUserRoles table and does not get me out to the AspNetRoles table which is where the name of the role exists.

Comment: @CosCallis, can you please update your answer and post your models? Because, generally there should be Navigation property from IdentityUserRole to IdentityRole

Comment: @AdilMammadov, I'm using the ApplicationUser:IdentityUser model that is provided with Asp.Net Identity 2.0 I agree there "should be" a navigation property, but I can't find it...that IS essentially the question.

Comment: @CosCallis but then the question should be *How to configure Identity models*. Please see my update for more info.

Comment: @AdilMammadov Thank you for your clarifications, this does seam overly complicated (and to no specific advantage) given the database schema which is provided by Identity. I had hoped that there was a more direct navigation path from User to Roles that didn't require "customization".

Comment: @CosCallis, there should be direct navigation property. İ just thougt that you have customized, but missing something. I do not know much about Identity. Please search a bit, you should find what is wrong with your models, before customizing